# Linkedin Campaing API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm having a problem listing the linkedin campaigns via API.

I was able to create the access key, I can access the data from my profile and the data from the My Company Page via the API, but I can not access the data of the campaigns:

I'm trying to run the get:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2/{campaign ID}

but it only returns me the error:

```
{
     "serviceErrorCode": 100,
     "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET / adCampaignsV2 / 140104704",
     "status": 403
}
```

I'm looking at linkedin documentation, but I do not think any answer
Please help me, please?

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions in your LinkedIn application settings ? https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/<app>/auth . The link to that page is on https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps

Comment: I get the same problem. And @MartinLockett yes all the permissions are checked in my application.